# Java Building a specific custom Comparator for Sorting

Tags: java, sql, orm

I am working on an ORM system (Object relational mapping, basically a wrapper in java classes such that I don't need to use SQL code directly)

This question goes about searching in a table, by specyfing constraints:

```
public final List<B> search(final AbstractConstraint... c) throws SearchException {
    if (c.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("orm.Manager.search: c.length == 0");
    }
    try {
        List<B> beans = new ArrayList<>();

        for (AbstractConstraint constraint : c) {
            try (PreparedStatement ps = new QueryBuilder(connection, tableName(), getPaths(), searchQuery()).add(constraint).build();
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    beans.add(createBean(rs));
                }
            }
        }

        if (c.length > 1) {
            boolean sorting = true;
            Field field = c[0].getField();
            Order order = c[0].getOrder();
            for (int i = 1; i < c.length; i++) {
                Field currentField = c[i].getField();
                Order currentOrder = c[i].getOrder();
                if (!field.equals(currentField) || !order.equals(currentOrder)) {
                    sorting = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (sorting) {
                //sort on field with comparator of supertype
            }
        }

        return beans;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Manager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw new SearchException(ex);
    }
}
```

Normally the AbstractConstraint itself takes care of the order. But there is a special case if you are using multiple AbstractConstraints (essentially my counterpart to the SQL `OR`). If two of those individual AbstractConstraints (which are already ordered), share the same ordering, then the resulting `List<B>` should be in total also ordered, and not contain two ordered lists stacked on top of eachother.

How would I go about doing that? This is what I know:

- The `Field` object, specyfing on which field should be searched, this is a direct reference to a column in a table in an SQL database.
- The `Order` object

So I am thinking that (in my current implementation), columns (thus fields) can have the following values:

- String (in SQL varchar)
- Integer (in SQL int)
- Date (in SQL datetime)
- BigInteger (in SQL decimal)

And the orderings would be ascending or descending.

How would I need to extend my `Field` class to capture the type of the column? This is all what Field is currently:

```
public interface Field {
    public String getFieldName();
}
```

And how would I write the `Comparator`? Actually, do I even have to write the `Comparator` or should I let `Field` implement `Comparable` in some way?

I hope the question is understandable and looking forward to any responses.

EDIT: Adding example of concrete implementation of `Field`:

```
public enum InvoiceFields implements Field {
    invoiceId("invoices.invoiceId"),
    businessPartnerId("invoices.businessPartnerId"),
    invoiceNumber("invoices.invoiceNumber"),
    invoiceDate("invoices.invoiceDate"),
    priceExclVAT("invoices.priceExclVAT"),
    VAT("invoices.VAT"),
    priceInclVAT("invoices.priceInclVAT"),
    paymentDiscount("invoices.paymentDiscount"),
    status("invoices.status");

    private final String enumName;

    private InvoiceFields(final String enumName) {
        this.enumName = enumName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFieldName() {
        return enumName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have heard of JPA, right? :).

Comment: @ColinMorelli Yes, forgot to add that I am more or less just interested in trying to write something myself. It started off as a small project because I thought JPA was hard, and I don't want to let my project die yet :P

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on what data structures you can use? E.g. why not let the sql handle the ordering? Why a `Field` implementation is an `enum` !?

Comment: The current restriction is that SQL handles one `AbstractConstraint` per time, rewriting that would be quite an hassle. `Field` is an enum, because you now can specify `AccountConstraint accountConstraint = new AccountConstraint.Builder().like().username("%e%").orderBy(AccountFields.age, Order.ASCENDING).build();` if you feel like retrieving all accounts with an e in their username and sort them by age.

Comment: And what classes does the `createBean()` return? Simple POJOs? (In your answer please use @c.s. so I am notified for your comment)

Comment: @c.s. It returns classes of type `B`. The class definition looks like `public abstract class Manager<B extends Bean, C extends AbstractConstraint> implements Closeable {` and `Bean` is just an interface without methods.

Comment: I am interested in what type of fields it has. i.e. if a row of resultset has: <Integer>, <String>, <Date> will those be converted to fields of that class or be stored in another structure like a `Map` for example

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an abstract class.  i.e then create subclasses for each of your different type of fields.

```
public abstract class Field implements Comparable<Field> {

public abstract String getFieldName();

public int compareTo(Field field) {
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't take care of the actual implementation of `compareTo` though, which is heavily dependant on the type of the `Field`, and that should also be captured somewhere.

Comment: Could you not just override the compareTo in the subclasses?

Comment: Added an example at the end of my OP. Don't think I just can do that.